# How to translate: multi-event and single-event

Tags: traduction, choix-de-mot, informatique, terminologie, mots-composés

**QUESTION 1:**

How can I translate this from english to french:

- *multi-event*
- *single-event*

Google Translate gives me:

- multi-événement
- événement unique

This first one sound right to me while the second doesn't sound correct to me, is that translated correctly?

**QUESTION 2:**

Just a bit longer expression. How can I translate this into french:

- *multi-event mobile application*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"**Single-event**" might also be translated by ***mono-événement*** but it would help if you tell more about the context.

"**Multi-event mobile application**" can be ***Application mobile multi-événement**"

Comment: Firstly I wanted to know how to say it alone. Then the context is mobile application. Anyway i think you already replied to my question. Thank you.

Comment: Googling "Multi-event mobile application" leads to a very limited number of hits. While "multi-événements" is generally a proper translation for "multi-event", it is still unclear for me what kind of events this application is handling.

Comment: For event I just mean event. Is not related to a specific kind of events, i wanted to know the general translation. I think the reply is correct.

Comment: In computing science, events can be keystrokes, screen touch gestures, button presses, interruptions, incoming call, battery level warnings, etc. In real-life, events can be appointments, holidays, meetings, breaking-news, etc. In any case, *événements* can be used for all of them so indeed a generic translation.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the context, if you're talking about software that are multi-threaded or not, you could use :

**Exécution Séquentielle** which means the program can only execute one operation at a time.

**Exécution Parallèles**  which means the program does handle multiple operation at a time.

To answer your specific translation request : multi-event mobile application could be said :

> "Application mobile parallélisée"

As multi-threaded programs tends to be used to simulate real-time reactions to inputs, you could also say

> "Application mobile en temps réel"